# Run Time error '1005' : Exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' was thrown for SSO login using VBA code. (UFT one)

Tags: vba, single-sign-on, hp-uft, alm

We need to open UFT and connect to ALM thru excel macros for SSO login. (UFT version 15.0.1, ALM version 15 and Excel version Microsoft office 365,64 bit)

**code to connect to ALM SSO login**

```vb
    Set objTDC = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
    objTDC.InitConnectionWithApiKey "http://<ALM server URL>:8080/qcbin","<Api-Key>","<Api-Key 
    Secret>"
    objTDC.Connect "<Domain>", "<Project>"
    approvalId= objTDC.GetApprovalID
```

**code to open UFT and connect to ALM SSO login**

```vb
    Set a = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
    a.TDConnection.ConnectWithApprovalID "http://<ALM server URL>:8080/qcbin", "<Domain>", " 
    <Project>", "<UserName>","" , approvalId, False
```

'getting Error at the above line.

**Error description** -
Run Time error '1005' :
Exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' was thrown.

**Note**
'Connection for Non SSO login is working fine in same excel macros and version of UFT and ALM.
below is the code for Non SSO login.
**Code for Non SSO login.**

```vb
    set tdc = TDConnection
    tdc.InitConnectionEx server
    tdc.Login login_name, password
    Set qt = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
    qt.TDConnection.Connect server, domain, project, login_name, password, False
    tdc.Connect domain, project
```